# "Request rate is large" error while importing JSON into Cosmos DB using Azure Data Migration Tool

Tags: json, data-migration, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a JSON file which contains 248 documents. I need to upload these documents to a collection (E.g. colFirst). The throughput provisioned for this collection/container is 400 RU/s. I am using the Azure Data Migration Tool (dtui.exe) to migrate documents from this JSON file into the Cosmos DB collection (colFirst).

I have set RU/s to 400 and specified a partition key under the "Target Information" section. When I try to import the JSON file, I get the "request rate is large" error and 113 documents are not imported while the others are. I tried attempting to import after a few minutes but that didn't seem to make a difference.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiiT7.jpg)

Has anyone faced this issue? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the tool could be a bit smarter and dynamically adjust its import speed to stay under the throughput limit! Try reducing the Number of Parallel Connections. The default is 10, so if you're not in an enormous hurry, change it to 1.